# Apache port 80 works but port 443 wont work with laravel project

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ssl

I install SSL certificate:

Now when I have simple index.html or some other file in public directory SSL works fine but when I point to index.php which is index of laravel 5.1 project I just get:

Not Found

The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server.

What is a problem? Why other SSL for other files works good just LARAVEL files (route) is a problem here...

WHta to do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Apache configuration is wrong, make sure SSL is installed correctly with Apache